# How to fix 'If(isset($_POST['Id'])) error' while editing the form in a PHP based CRUD application?

Tags: php, crud, insert-update, isset

The "if(isset($_POST["titleId"]) && !empty($_POST["titleId"])" in my code is returning false value.

I'm working on a CRUD application, the insert modal is working fine, now I'm stuck at the update part of it.  So when you click on the update icon it does fetch the right titleId in the URL but the first 'if' condition returns false and hence the update isn't working.

Here's what I've tried so far.

```
admin.php
<?php
$typeId = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "type");
$titleId = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "titleId");
$active = "admin" . $typeId;
require_once './pages/header.php';
require_once './functions/queries.php';
$getAll = Queries::getAllTitle($typeId);




?>
<div class="container">
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="page-header clearfix">
                        <h2 class="pull-left"></h2>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#facultyAddModal">Add Title</button> 
                    </div>

<!--<div class="container">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#facultyAddModal">Add Title</button>    
    <br><br>-->
    <div class="panel-group" id="titleAccordion">
        <?php      
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($getAll); $i++) {         
            echo <<<HTML
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading"><h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#titleAccordion" href="#collapseF{$i}">{$getAll[$i]['title']}</a></h4>
                    </div>
                        <div id="collapseF{$i}" class="panel-collapse collapse" >
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="table-responsive">
                                <table class="table table-condensed"><tbody>
                                <tr><td>Title:</td><td>{$getAll[$i]['title']}</td></tr>
                                <tr><td>Units:</td><td>{$getAll[$i]['units']}</td></tr>
                                <tr><td>Category:</td><td>{$getAll[$i]['category']}</td></tr>  
                            <tr><td>
                                <tr><td><input type="hidden" id="titleId" name="titleId" value="{$getAll[$i]['titleId']}"> </tr><td>
                             <a href='edit.php?titleId={$getAll[$i]['titleId']}' title='Update Record' data-toggle='tooltip'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span></a>
                             <a href='delete.php?titleId={$getAll[$i]['titleId']}' title='Delete Record' data-toggle='tooltip'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span></a>
                            </tr></td>

                                </tbody></table>      
                            </div>

                      </div>
                     </div>  
                </div>
HTML;
       }
       ?>
    </div>
            </div>    
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>    


<!--    Title Add Modal-->

       <div class="modal fade" id="facultyAddModal" role="dialog">
           <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content"> 
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Add Title</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                 <div id="adminResult" class="hide" role="alert">
               <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                 <div id="resultAdminContent"></div>
                </div>  
                    <form class="cmxform" id="adminForm" method="post">
                <label for="Activity">ActivityAttended (required)</label>
                <input class="form-control" id="adminTitle" name="title" type="text" required>
            <br>
                <label for="units">Units (required)</label>
                <input class="form-control" id="adminUnits" type="number" name="units" required>
            <br>
                <label for="Category">Category (Optional)</label>
                <input class="form-control" id="adminCategory" type="text" name="category">
            <br>
                <?php echo 
                 '<input type="hidden" id="addadminTypeId" value="'.$typeId.'">';
                ?>
                <?php echo 
                 '<input type="hidden" id="titleId" name="titleId" value="'.$titleId.'">';
                ?>

                <button class="btn btn-info btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
            <br>
            <br>
        </form>
          </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>


update.php

<?php
require_once 'functions/db_connection.php';
 $conn = DB::databaseConnection();
$title = $units = $category = "";  

if(isset($_POST["titleId"]) && !empty($_POST["titleId"])){

        $titleId = $_POST['titleId'];


        $sql =  "UPDATE title SET title = :title, units = :units, category = :category WHERE titleId = :titleId";

       if($stmt = $conn->prepare($sql))
        {
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
           $stmt->bindParam(':titleId', $titleId);          
           $stmt->bindParam(':title', $title);
           $stmt->bindParam(':units', $units);
           $stmt->bindParam(':category', $category);
           if ($stmt->execute()) {
              header("location: index.php");
                exit();
            } else{
                echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            } 

        unset($stmt);
    }


    unset($conn);
} else{

    if(isset($_GET["titleId"]) && !empty(trim($_GET["titleId"]))){
        $titleId =  trim($_GET["titleId"]);

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM title WHERE titleId = :titleId";
        if($stmt = $conn->prepare($sql))
        {
            $stmt->bindParam(':titleId', $titleId); 
            if ($stmt->execute()){
                   if($stmt->rowCount() == 1){
                $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);    
                    // Retrieve individual field value
                    $title = $result["title"];
                    $units = $result["units"];
                    $category = $result["category"];
                } else{
                    echo"error1";
                    exit();
                }

            } else{
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
        }


        unset($stmt);


        unset($conn);
    }  else{
        // URL doesn't contain id parameter. Redirect to error page
        echo"error2";
        exit();
    }
}
?>

<!--<!DOCTYPE html>-->
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Update Record</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        .wrapper{
            width: 500px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="page-header">
                        <h2>Update Record</h2>
                    </div> 
    <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])); ?>" method="post">
                <label for="Activity">Title</label>
                <input class="form-control" id="adminTitle" name="title" type="text" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" required>

            <br>
                <label for="units">Units (required)</label>
                <input class="form-control" id="adminUnits" type="number" name="units" value="<?php echo $units; ?>" required>
            <br>
                <label for="Category">Category (Optional)</label>
                <input class="form-control" id="adminCategory" type="text" value="<?php echo $category; ?>" name="category">
            <br>
                <input type="hidden"  name="titleId" value="<?php echo $titleId; ?>">
                <button class="btn btn-info btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
            <br>

            <br>
        </form>
                </div>
            </<div> 
        </div>   
       </div>      
    </div>        
</body>
</html>
```

The only goal here is to get the update form working, the user should be able to update the records of the respective title being selected.

Comment: Name fields should be unique. You have multiple `name="titleId"` which means you will not get the data you think you will

Comment: By the way, `!empty` also checks for isset, so you can remove the isset check.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know crud but I think there is a way to debug a little:

e.g. try this:

```
if(isset($_POST["titleId"]) && !empty($_POST["titleId"])){
   // test if you are here:
   echo 'hi, yeah I am here!';
}
```

or this

```
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($_POST);
echo '</pre>';
// before:
if(isset($_POST["titleId"]) && !empty($_POST["titleId"])){
    // ...
}
```

also, take a look at

```
error_get_last()['message']
```

Comment: CRUD is an acronym for Create, read, update and delete :) See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete

Comment: aha ok, I thought it was a new php version, like Storm etc. xDD  but probably does not change the fact that he tries to catch a get by post :)

Comment: Hey, I tried debugging that way already, before the post, and I put an else echo"error" too.. the output was "error"

Comment: Also, I didn't  get the second part of your answer, can you please explain?

Comment: Also - Storm isn't a PHP version - it's an IDE.